# how to search a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I have a table called Speeches and a Speakers. There is a pivot table called Speeche_Speakers, as it is many to many.

I want to do a search, for example, get a speaker and filter all the speeches that have that speaker, but I'm having difficulty because it's a pivot table

The code below is from the index method, where I show all the records and where the filter request comes from

In the past it was one to one, so there is a part of the filter of these speakers, it is commented because it no longer works, because as I said, now there is the pivot table because we turn a lot to many

```
            if(!Gate::allows('Lista palestra')){
                flash('<i class="bi bi-ban"></i> Você não tem acesso a isso!')->warning();
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }

            $data = Speeche::query();

            if($request->filled('search')){
                $searchFor = findStr($request->input('search'));
                $data = $data->whereRaw("CONCAT( COALESCE(speeches.id,' '), COALESCE(speeches.title,' ')) REGEXP '{$searchFor}'");
            }

            if($request->filled('schedule_id')){
                $data = $data->where("speeches.schedule_id", $request->input('schedule_id'));
            }

            if($request->filled('speaker_id')){
//                $data = $data->where("speeches.speaker_id", $request->input('speaker_id'));
            }

            if($request->filled('status')){
                $data = $data->where("status", $request->input('status'));
            }
            else{
                $data = $data->where("status", 1);
            }

            $data = $data->with('schedule', 'speecheSpeakers.speaker');
            $data = $data->paginate(10)->appends($_GET);

            $searchProps = Speeche::searchProps();
            $status = GeneralStatusEnum::cases();

            return view('admin.speeches.index', compact('data', 'searchProps', 'status'));
```

Comment: You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77648054/edit) and include your Models and their relationship. You'll likely have this in `Speech`: `public function speakers() { return $this->belongsToMany(Speech::class); }`, and the opposite in `Speaker` (or whatever). You'd then query via `Speech::whereHas('speakers', function ($query) { ... })->get()`, replace `...` with the search criteria. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many and https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations will contain all the info you need.

Answer (score -1):

You can try modifying your code to join with the pivot table and filter by `speaker_id`

```
if($request->filled('speaker_id')){
    $speakerId = $request->input('speaker_id');
    $data = $data->whereHas('speecheSpeakers', function($query) use ($speakerId) {
        $query->where('speaker_id', $speakerId);
    });
}
```

Also confirm that the `speecheSpeakers` relationship in your `Speeche model` is set up correctly like the following

```
public function speecheSpeakers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Speaker::class, 'Speeche_Speakers');
}
```